# Is the void() in decltype(void()) an expression or is it a function type?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, void, decltype

This is a follow-up of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39278200/is-sizeofvoid-a-legal-expression) question, more precisely of the comments of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39278306/4987285) answer.

What does the `void()` in `decltype(void())` represent exactly?
Does it represent a function type, an expression or whatever?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using a [hyperlinked C++ grammar](http://www.nongnu.org/hcb/#decltype-specifier), the parsing of `decltype(void())` is:

```
decltype( expression )
decltype( assignment-expression )
decltype( conditional-expression )
```

... lots of steps involving order of operations go here ...

```
decltype( postfix-expression )
decltype( simple-type-specifier ( expression-listopt ) )
decltype( void() )
```

So `void()` is a kind of [`expression`](http://www.nongnu.org/hcb/#expression) here, in particular a [`postfix-expression`](http://www.nongnu.org/hcb/#postfix-expression).

Specifically, quoting section 5.2.3 [expr.type.conf] paragraph 2 of the 2011 ISO C++ standard:

> The expression `T()`, where `T` is a *simple-type-specifier* or
>   *typename-specifier* for a non-array complete object type or the (possibly cv-qualified) `void` type, creates a prvalue of the
>   specified type, which is value-initialized (8.5; no initialization is
>   done for the `void()` case).

So `void()` is an expression of type `void`, just as `int()` is an expression of type `int` (with value `0`). Clearly a void expression has no value, but here it's the operand of `decltype`, so it's not evaluated. `decltype` refers only to its operand's type, not its value.

`decltype(void())` is simply a verbose way of referring to the type `void`.

Comment: @skypjack: See the C++11 standard (or a draft), section 5.2.3 [expr.type.conv], paragraph 2.  A *simple-type-specifier* followed by empty parentheses "creates a prvalue of the specified type,which is valueinitialized (8.5; no initialization is done for the void() case)". Just as `int()` is an expression of type `int`, `void()` is an expression of type `void`. And since it's the operand of `decltype`, it's not evaluated. `decltype(void())` is just a complex way of referring to the type `void`. (Yakk, you might want to expand your answer to explain how `void()` is an expression.)

Comment: @Yakk As already mentioned in the comments, expanding the answer with more details would help. +1 to promote the suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding an explanation of what `void()` means. Please check my update for accuracy.

Answer (score 6):

I'm quoting the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39278306/4987285) of @JoachimPileborg that seems to explain it correctly:

> I think I figured it out now, decltype needs an expression, and not a type. void() is not actually a type here, but an expression, a C-style cast (just like e.g. int(12.34)) void(void) is not an expression therefore it doesn't work. How the compiler parses different things depends on the context, when it expects a type it parses as a type, when it expects an expression it parses as an expression. sizeof() (with the parentheses) expects first of all a type, otherwise it's parsed as a parenthesized expression.

I'm not looking for credits or reputation.
Anyway, I guess that was an interesting answer in the answer that is worth of a dedicated question for future readers.

Comment: If you don't want rep, you can mark the answer as Community Wiki

Comment: @skypjack click "edit" then check the box "community wiki" below the text window

Comment: `void()` is not a C-style cast. In C, a cast consists of a parenthesized type name followed by an expression, for example `(void)42`. In `void()`, the type name is not parenthesized and it's not followed by an expression.

Comment: @KeithThompson Feel free to add your own question. As you can see, there is not an accepted one.