# Differences between decltype(void()) and decltype(void{})

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, void, decltype

This is a follow-up of the question: [What does the `void()` in `decltype(void())` mean exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39279074/what-does-the-void-in-decltypevoid-mean-exactly).

---

`decltype(void())` compiles fine and what the `void()` means in this case is explained in the above mentioned question (actually in the answer).
On the other side, I noticed that `decltype(void{})` doesn't compile.

What's the difference between them (in the context of a `decltype` at least)?
Why doesn't the second expression compile?

---

For completeness, it follows a minimal (not-)working example:

```
int main() {
    // this doesn't compile
    //decltype(void{}) *ptr = nullptr;
    // this compiles fine
    decltype(void()) *ptr = nullptr;
    (void)ptr;
}
```

Comment: Because "List-initialization is initialization of an object or reference from a braced-init-list." :) But wait.. that's not true! `int{}` does not initialize an object, I hear you say. Well, then there's the big bullet list with lots of cases, and with no `void` case :)

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Well, touché, but it can be used with `int`. It is neither an object nor a reference. Why cannot be used with `void` in an unevaluated context?

Comment: @W.F. Suppressing warnings about unused variables, nothing more. :-)

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Ahahah you modified your comment while I was writing mine!! Where is that bullet list? Damnit!

Comment: @W.F. No, it shouldn't. Stuff for your next question? :-D

Comment: @skypjack ok I got the point :)

Comment: @skypjack conceptually, `type{}` is not the degenerate case of a cast, like it is `type()`. It only shares most of its syntax. Since the former is "uniform initialization", it behaves the same when you write `type t{}`, `: member{}`  etc. And in all cases, `void` is not allowed. So, uniform ill-formed-ness here.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I like the way you _explain_. Write that as an answer, it seems to me that you got the point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`void()` is interpreted as type-id when used with `sizeof`.
`void()` is interpreted as an expression when used with `decltype`.

I don't think `void{}` is valid in any context. It is neither a valid type-id nor a valid expression.

Answer (score 4):

(Building on discussion in the question comments)

**Note:** I was referencing C++17 or close-to for the answer. C++14 works the same way, the text difference is noted near the end of the answer.

`void()` is a special exception. See N4618 5.2.3 **[expr.type.conv]**, emphasis mine:

> 1 A ***simple-type-speciﬁer*** (7.1.7.2) or *typename-speciﬁer* (14.6) **followed by a parenthesized optional *expression-list* or by a *braced-init-list*** (the initializer) constructs a value of the speciﬁed type given the initializer. If the type is a placeholder for a deduced class type, it is replaced by the return type of the function selected by overload resolution for class template deduction (13.3.1.8) for the remainder of this section.
>
> 2 If the initializer is a parenthesized single expression, the type conversion expression is equivalent (in deﬁnedness, and if deﬁned in meaning) to the corresponding cast expression (5.4). **If the type is (possibly cv-qualiﬁed) void and the initializer is (), the expression is a prvalue of the speciﬁed type that performs no initialization.** Otherwise, the expression is a prvalue of the speciﬁed type whose result object is direct-initialized (8.6) with the initializer. For an expression of the form T(), T shall not be an array type.

So `void()` is only valid because it's explicitly identified in **[expr.type.conv]/2** as *no initialization*. `void{}` doesn't meet that exception, so it attempts to be a *direct-initialized* object.

**tl;dr** here through C++14 notes: You cannot *direct-initialize* a `void` object.

Rabbit-holing through N4618 8.6 **[dcl.init]** to see what's actually going on with `void{}`

- 8.6/16 => *direct-initialization*
- 8.6/17.1 => *list-initialized*, jump to 8.6.4
- 8.6.4/3.10 => *value-initialized*

  - `void()` would have shortcut the above three with 8.6/11 => *value-initialized*, and then rejoined the trail, which is why the special exception in **[expr.type.conv]** is needed.
- 8.6/8.4 => *zero-initialized*

Now, 8.6/6 defines *zero-initialize* for:

- *scalar*
- *non-union class type*
- *union type*
- *array type*
- *reference type*

N4618 3.9 **[basic.types]/9** defines *scalar*:

> Arithmetic types (3.9.1), enumeration types, pointer types, pointer to member types(3.9.2), **std::nullptr_t**, and cv-qualiﬁed versions of these types (3.9.3) are collectively called *scalar types*.

N4618 3.9.1 **[basic.fundamental]/8** defines *arithmetic types*:

> Integral and ﬂoating types are collectively called *arithmetic types*.

So `void` is not an *arithmetic type*, so it's not a *scalar*, so it cannot be *zero-initialized*, so it cannot be *value-initialized*, so it cannot be *direct-initialized*, so the expression is not valid.

Apart from the initialisation, `void()` and `void{}` would work the same way, producing a *prvalue* expression of type `void`. Even though you cannot have a *result object* for an incomplete type, and `void` is *always* incomplete:

N4618 3.9.1 **[basic.fundamental]/9** (bold mine):

> A **type cv void is an incomplete type** that cannot be completed; such a type has an empty set of values.

`decltype` specifically allows incomplete types:

N4618 7.1.7.2 **[decl.type.simple]/5** (bold mine):

> If the operand of a *decltype-speciﬁer* is a prvalue, the temporary materialization conversion is not applied (4.4) and no result object is provided for the prvalue. **The type of the prvalue may be incomplete.**

---

In C++14, N4296 5.2.3 **[expr.type.conv]** is differently worded. The braced form was almost an afterthought to the parenthesised version:

> A *simple-type-speciﬁer* (7.1.6.2) or *typename-speciﬁer* (14.6) followed by a parenthesized *expression-list* constructs a value of the speciﬁed type given the expression list. If the expression list is a single expression, the type conversion expression is equivalent (in deﬁnedness, and if deﬁned in meaning) to the corresponding cast expression (5.4). If the type speciﬁed is a class type, the class type shall be complete. If the expression list speciﬁes more than a single value,the type shall be a class with a suitably declared constructor(8.5,12.1), and the expression `T(x1, x2, ...)` is equivalent in eﬀect to the declaration `T t(x1, x2, ...)`; for some invented temporary variable t, with the result being the value of t as a prvalue.
>
> The expression T(), where T is a `simple-type-speciﬁer` or `typename-speciﬁer` for a non-array complete object type or the (possibly cv-qualiﬁed) `void` type, creates a prvalue of the speciﬁed type, whose value is that produced by value-initializing (8.5) an object of type T; no initialization is done for the void() case. [*Note:* if `T` is a non-class type that is cv-qualiﬁed, the *cv-qualiﬁers* are discarded when determining the type of the resulting prvalue (Clause 5). *—end note*]
>
> Similarly, a *simple-type-speciﬁer* or *typename-speciﬁer* followed by a *braced-init-list* creates a temporary object of the speciﬁed type direct-list-initialized (8.5.4) with the speciﬁed *braced-init-list*, and its value is that temporary object as a prvalue.

The effect is the same for our purposes, the [change](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/611f4c675e2160463cb1fbf71ab87bd67c9102eb) relates to [P0135R1 Wording for guaranteed copy elision through simplified value categories](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0135r1.html), which removed temporary object creation from expressions. Instead, the context of the expression provides a result object to be initialised by the expression, if the context needs it.

As noted above, `decltype` (unlike `sizeof` or `typeid`) doesn't provide a result-object for the expression, which is why `void()` works even though it cannot initialise a result object.

---

I feel that the exception in N4618 5.2.3 **[expr.type.conv]** ought to be applied to `void{}` too. It means that guidelines around `{}` get more complex. See for example [ES.23: Prefer the {} initializer syntax](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Res-list) in the C++ Core Guidelines, which would currently recommend `decltype(void{})` over `decltype(void())`. `decltype(T{})` is more likely to be where this one bites you...

Comment: A bit late, but apparently a good answer. Thank you. I'll read it carefully as soon as possible.

Comment: Re-reading the C++14 version, I think it ("Similarly") would have allowed `void{}` which is now explicitly excluded. This seems even more like a defect to me now.