# Is void{} legal or not?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, void, c++17, return-type-deduction

This is a follow-up up of [Differences between decltype(void()) and decltype(void{})](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39300653/).

In the comments and in the answer it is said more than once that `void{}` is *neither a valid type-id nor a valid expression*.

However, I came through [[7.1.7.4.1/2]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto#dcl.type.auto.deduct-2) (*placeholder type deduction*) of the working draft, which says:

> [...]
>
> - for a non-discarded `return` statement that occurs in a function declared with a return type that contains a placeholder type, `T` is the declared return type and `e` is the operand of the `return` statement. If the `return` statement has no operand, then `e` is `void{}`;
>   [...]

So, is `void{}` (conceptually) legal, or should the working draft use `void()`?

If it's acceptable as mentioned in the working draft (even though only as an *- as if it's a -* statement), it must be legal indeed. This means that `decltype(void{})` should be valid as well, as an example.

Is there anything wrong with my reasoning?
What exactly is the `void{}` mentioned in the bullet above and why is it a legal expression in this case?

Comment: Sounds like the standard is a little messed up here.

Comment: I would (weakly) suspect a working draft error...  Which is why it is a *working draft* and not a standard?  :)

Comment: @Yakk: It's still a good idea to submit an issue on it, of course.

Comment: @NicolBolas If you are submitting an issue, please post here the link. Thanks. I would do that, but I don't even know how to do that!! :-)

Comment: @Yakk Well, it's quite uncommon for me to note an error in the working draft indeed!! :-)

Comment: @NicolBolas Meanwhile I sent an email to the discussion group. I'll be back with news if someone will reply.

Comment: This seems obvious enough to me that I just sent in https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/pull/917

Comment: @T.C. I'm not skilled enough to say _obvious_ about an error in the working draft. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Confirmed the bug. Already fixed.
[Here](https://isocpp.org/forums/iso-c-standard-discussion?place=topic%2Fstd-discussion%2Fg6Rpo1NSHOw%2Fdiscussion) is the discussion (pretty short to be honest).

So, the answer is - *no, `void{}` is not legal*.
It was a wording bug of the working draft.

Comment: This answer is now obsolete and the link is dead.

Answer (score 12):

To me it sounds like someone messed up merging the previous standard with the new one.

Previously the standard said this: (C++14 N4140, 7.1.6.4.7 [dcl.spec.auto]):

> When a [...] `return` statement occurs in a function
>   declared with a return type that contains a placeholder type, the deduced return type or variable type
>   is determined from the type of its initializer. In the case of a `return` with no operand, the initializer is
>   considered to be `void()`.

The newer standard allows for `if constexpr` statements, so the language needed to change to reflect that.  `if constexpr` leads to the concept of a potentially *discarded* `return` statement (if the `return` is in the not-taken branch of a constexpr if, then it's discarded and the return type is inferred from other return statements, if any).

Probably the new wording should be something like:

> for a non-discarded return statement that occurs in a function
>   declared with a return type that contains a placeholder type, `T` is the
>   declared return type and `e` is the operand of the `return` statement. If
>   the return statement has no operand, then `T` is `auto` and the deduced return type is `void`

Comment: 1. Type should be `void()`, neither `void{}` nor `void`. 2. You didn't reply actually to the question in the title: is `void{}` legal? No, it isn't. :-) 3. Not sure `constexpr if` is guilty for the error. Why did you say that? Thank you anyway for the detailed answer.

Comment: @skypjack: No, the type should not be `void()`.  The wording currently says `e` is `void{}`, AndyG just talks about the type without ever trying to write an expression for `e`.

Comment: N4296 is a C++17 draft. The C++14 text is N4140. The text you quoted differs between C++14 and N4296.

Comment: @M.M that's good to know. I'm too cheap to get the real text, so I used the fallback isocpp recommends (N4296).

Comment: N4140 is freely available, would be a good idea to revise your answer (either to use N4140's quote; or to not claim the quote is from C++14)

Comment: @BenVoigt Got it. Right. Thank you. Other questions still apply.

Comment: @M.M; Changed the answer to reflect N4140. Thanks for the heads-up. Hope all's good, mate.

Answer (score 4):

#### `void{}` is a valid expression

There is no difference between the expressions `void()` and `void{}` in modern C++. Both are legal.
The current wording in [[expr.type.conv] p2](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.type.conv#2) states:

> Otherwise, if the type is *cv* `void` and the initializer is `()` or `{}` (after pack expansion, if any), the expression is a prvalue of type `void` that performs no initialization.

`void{}` still isn't a valid type and `T{}` isn't a valid type in general. Braces aren't a valid way of constructing a declarator, and thus a type.

#### Historically, this wasn't always the case

Historically, there used to a be a difference, but [CWG Issue 2351 `void{}`](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2351.html) has made `void{}` valid as a defect report, meaning that it retroactively applies to C++11 and more recent standards.

The section in the working draft which you have quoted no longer exists in that form, and was just a temporary mistake. `void{}` was not valid back then and the author had made a mistake when using `void{}` as if it was valid.